# Problem getting data from callback(data):

Tags: python, callback, ros

I am still struggling with using data from the callback function, I wrote a class and trying to get the data from the callback function associated with the class, any help would be much appreciated. Do I need to use multi threading or there is an easy way to use it ? When I am calling the class the publisher initializes and then callback keep getting the updated data but I am not sure how can I use this data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""OpenCV feature detectors with ros CompressedImage Topics in python.

This example subscribes to a ros topic containing sensor_msgs 
CompressedImage. It converts the CompressedImage into a numpy.ndarray, 
then detects and marks features in that image. It finally displays 
and publishes the new image - again as CompressedImage topic.
"""

__version__=  '0.1'

from moveit_commander.conversions import pose_to_list
from rospy_tutorials.msg import Floats
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
from tf import TransformListener
from std_msgs.msg import String
import geometry_msgs.msg
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
from math import pi
import sys, time
import rospy
import copy

VERBOSE=False

class move_xarm:

    # global my_data
    
    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialize ros publisher and subscriber'''
        # publish trajectories for RViz to visualize
        self.display_trajectory_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/move_group/display_planned_path',moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory,queue_size=20)

        self.data_callback_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/callback_data',numpy_msg(Floats),queue_size=1)
        
        self.my_data = None
        self.listener()
        # subscribed Topic 
        # self.subscriber = rospy.Subscriber("marker_wrt_base_pose", numpy_msg(Floats), self.callback, queue_size = 1)
        if VERBOSE :
            print("subscribed to marker_wrt_base_pose")

        
    def listener(self):

        # In ROS, nodes are uniquely named. If two nodes with the same
        # name are launched, the previous one is kicked off. The
        # anonymous=True flag means that rospy will choose a unique
        # name for our 'listener' node so that multiple listeners can
        # run simultaneously.
        rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_tutorial', anonymous=True)
        

        rospy.Subscriber("marker_wrt_base_pose", numpy_msg(Floats), self.callback,queue_size = 1)
        
        # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
        rospy.spin()
    
    def callback(self, ros_data):
        '''Callback function of subscribed topic. 
        Here position data get converted into float64'''
        if VERBOSE :
            print('received data of type: "%s"' % ros_data.format)

        self.my_data = ros_data.data
        # my_data = my_data.astype('float64')
       

        self.data_callback_publisher.publish(ros_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    mv = move_xarm()
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. How exactly do you want to use the data? Your code will currently get the data when published and republish it out.

Comment: @BTables I want to use the data from callback into another function continuous such that I can update the position of the robot accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue,

1. Create another function out of the class say name use_data(args)
2. Call use_data in main function and you are good to go.

One of the common problem is use of spin command,they block the main thread from exiting until ROS invokes a shutdown - via a Ctrl + C.

```
def use_data(args):

    ic = move_xarm()

    rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_tutorial',anonymous=True)

    rate = rospy.Rate(5) # ROS Rate at 5Hz

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
     do stuff using the variable ic.my_data
     rate.sleep()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to call `rospy.init_node()` before using other rospy methods like `rospy.Publisher` etc. or in your case before initializing `ic = move_xarm()`